# Near perfect self balanced binary search tree?

Tags: binary-tree, avl-tree, red-black-tree

I understand AVL and Red Black are implementations of self balancing trees. But I'm curious how difficult it would be actually create a near as possible self balancing tree. To the point where the height could only be off my one node in no more than 1 branch. This would likely involve a lot of rotations. Has this been done/implemented?

Comment: In the extreme, this makes the tree structure redundant. A sorted `Vector` or `ArrayList` could be seen as such a tree expressed implicitly in-order, with binary search just implicitly following the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe AVL Trees actually satisfy your condition. In an AVL tree, the heights of the two child subtrees of any node differ by at most one; if at any time they differ by more than one, rebalancing is done to restore this property.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree

Comment: Ok, so my real question is can a tree achieve height < 1.44log(n). Something more like height < 1.1log(n). Does that mean the only option is to move away from BSTs and towards a 2-3 tree or something else?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. I'm thinking of simple degenerate cases, like a 2-item tree is going to have height=2 no matter which tree balancer you use.